# Pattern matching of nested list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to use nested lists of nestedness 2 to represent matrix (e.g. `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`). How would I define a function that process small submatrices (say 2*2)? I expected something like this:
`f (a1:a2:a) : (b1:b2:b) : x = ...`
Where a1, a2 are two consecutive elements of first row and b1, b2 — second row. a, b are rests of first and second row correspondigly. x is the rest of matrix rows.

But this clearly doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In what way does it not work?  We need more details to help.

Comment: @Paul Johnson thanks but the answer is already given.

Comment: If you have a fixed number of items, use tuples. If it's not fixed, don't code against a specific number of items.

Comment: Offtopic: If you don't mind me asking, is Haskell what you are being/was taught at university/school?

Comment: @delnan I need to work with 2*2 submatrices so I need to code it somewhere. Of curse, there would be two patterns for function to match: one for matrix that has 2*2 submatrix anr one for all other cases (through wildcard).

Comment: @Yasir Arsanukaev I'm a PhD student studing Haskell myself as I am to act as a TA in the next term on the course on functional programming which uses Haskell. Now I'm solving problems from Project Euler (projecteuler.net) on Haskell in order to get a training.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I expected something like this: `f (a1:a2:a) : (b1:b2:b) : x = ...`

You've got the right idea. All you're missing is a pair of parentheses:

```
f ((a1:a2:a) : (b1:b2:b) : x) = ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget you can just use a bit of `where` syntax

```
f xs = ...
    where (a1:a2:a) = head xs
          (b1:b2:b) = head (tail xs)
          x         = tail (tail xs)
```

It's worth noting, however, that pattern matching gives you the benefit of falling down to the next definition of the function if the pattern doesn't match. It would take more guards and stuff to make this `where` version do that.

Comment: It never made sense to me that (a:b:c) could be the left side of an equation, that it was always a specification of inputs, only. That is until I saw you do this. It's like (a,b) = (c,d) but with lists instead of tuples. This means a whole lot to me. TY!